# Find the exponential distribution cdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've only reached up to this point:

1. $F_Y(y)=\Bbb P(Y\leqslant y)$
2. $\Bbb P(\exp(-X)\leqslant y)$
3. $\Bbb P(X \geqslant -\ln(y))$
4. $1- \Bbb P(X\leqslant -\ln(y))$
5. $1- F_X(-\ln(y))$

   ???

Only up to here.

Now I guess that the value we get from here should equal the Beta c.d.f but I'm lost now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_X$ and $f_Y$ denote the probability density functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively. Since $X \sim \exp(\lambda)$,
$$f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}.$$
Let $Y = g(X) = e^{-X}$. Since $g$ is invertible,
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= f_X(g^{-1}(y))\bigg\lvert \frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\bigg\lvert \\
&= \lambda y^{\lambda - 1}.
\end{align}

You might be interested to look into change of variables.

Answer (score 0):

A Beta$(\alpha,\beta)$ distributed random variable with parameters $\alpha,\beta>0$ is an absolutely continuous random variable with density function
$$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}, \quad 0<x<1,$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the gamma function.

Let $Y=e^{-X}$, then $X=-\log(Y)$. Observe that the support of $X$ is $(0,\infty)$ and hence the support of $Y$ is $(0,1)$. Observe also that the transformation is bijective.

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y) = P(e^{-X}\leq y)= P(-X \leq \log(y)) = P(X\geq -\log(y))=1-P(X\leq -\log(y)) = 1-F_X(-\log(y)).$$

You know that $1-F_X(x)=e^{-\lambda x}$ if $X\sim exp(\lambda)$. Hence,
$$F_Y(y)=e^{\lambda \log(y)} = y^{\lambda},\quad 0< y < 1.$$

Since $F_Y$ is continuously differentiable on $(0,1)$ we find
$$f_Y(y) = \lambda y^{\lambda -1} = \frac{\Gamma(\lambda +1)}{\Gamma(\lambda) \Gamma(1)} y^{\lambda -1} (1-y)^{(1-1)},$$
and we see that $Y\sim Beta(\lambda,1)$.

I see you might have used a different parametrization of the exponential distribution, that is why you obtain $1/\lambda$ instead of $\lambda$.